# Converting a deep learning model from GPU powered framework, such as Theano, to a common, easily handled one, such as Numpy

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, keras, lasagne

I have been playing around with building some deep learning models in Python and now I have a couple of outcomes I would like to be able to show friends and family.

Unfortunately(?), most of my friends and family aren't really up to the task of installing any of the advanced frameworks that are more or less necessary to have when creating these networks, so I can't just send them my scripts in the present state and hope to have them run. 
But then again, I have already created the nets, and just using the finished product is considerably less demanding than making it. We don't need advanced graph compilers or GPU compute powers for the show and tell. We just need the ability to make a few matrix multiplications.

"Just" being a weasel word, regrettably. What I would like to do is convert the the whole model (connectivity,functions and parameters) to a model expressed in e.g. regular Numpy (which, though not part of standard library, is both much easier to install and easier to bundle reliably with a script)

I fail to find any ready solutions to do this. (I find it difficult to pick specific keywords on it for a search engine). But it seems to me that I can't be the first guy who wants to use a ready-made deep learning model on a lower-spec machine operated by people who aren't necessarily inclined to spend months learning how to set the parameters in an artificial neural network.
Are there established ways of transferring a model from e.g. Theano to Numpy?

I'm not necessarily requesting those specific libraries.  The main point is I want to go from a GPU-capable framework in the creation phase to one that is trivial to install or bundle in the usage phase, to alleviate or eliminate the threshold the dependencies create for users without extensive technical experience.

Comment: the cpu version of tensorflow is as easy to install for a linux installs as numpy is.. you just as to package the wheel file.

Comment: and here is the numpy wheel , for linux, again https://pypi.python.org/packages/ae/34/1b5838ae482992fcc4f2d00ced6bb1dde58f4abb352a4af65a9f13ce9dd7/numpy-1.11.1-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=44944748be64b99ae5d793d285247964

Comment: tensorflow cpu wheel https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

Comment: if your friends are on windows, you'll most likely have to convert your forward pass to numpy by hand and load the trained/saved matrix from the tensorflow implementation as afaik tensorflow doesn't support windows

Comment: so yeah, linux easy, windows.. pretty hard.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out  Julius. I'm afraid in addition to working on actual respectable operating systems the solution would also need to run on Microsoft® Windows®. That is a not insignificant part of the reason I would like to be able convert.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting option for you would be to deploy your project to heroku, like explained on this page:

https://github.com/sugyan/tensorflow-mnist

Comment: Interesting information to be aware of, but I feel in the present cases it's not a good fit. Thanks anyway for what may well turn out to be useful at some point.

Comment: ah! there is a docker container for the cpu version of tensorflow. you could use that to package your project to your friends

Comment: you can modify this https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#docker-installation to carry your code and trained model. they will then be able to run it on most x86 machines